# MVC Action Link Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.actionlink

I have come across what appears to be an inconsistency in MVC 5 regarding the Html.Actionlink.  In different cshtml files I can use the same code, but the url target that is generated is different.

For example, this line of code:

`<td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Edit", new { item.ParentTableID }) </td>`

generates this URL

`localhost\MyControllerClass\Edit?ParentTableID=35`

That then properly calls the ActionView method Edit and feeds the parameter with 35 as expected.

However, in another cshtml file, this line

`<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditChild", new { id = f.ApplicationTableFieldID})</td>`

produces this url

`localhost/MyControllerClass/Edit/7`

and when it hits the EditChild Action View, the parameter is null.

I have seen this now a couple of times and not yet been able to understand what makes the difference.  But I need the first result.

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know the anwer, but in each of your action links, for the parameters, you specify 'id' = f.ApplicationTableFieldID and in the other one, you just have item.ParentTableID. Have you tried making them the same? In terms of having `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditChild", new {f.ApplicationTableFieldID})`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your ID parameters are named correctly in both your Action method and your ActionLink Html helper.  The visual difference comes from MVC *default* routing and how it can take a parameter named `ID` and put it in the URL without the query string (? followed by stuff)

If your action method looks like this

```
public ActionResult EditChild(int ParentTableID){}
```

Then you will need to have your ID parameter named ParentTableID when you pass it back in your URL

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditChild", new { ParentTableID = f.ApplicationTableFieldID})</td>
```

Should now produce the following URL

```
localhost\MyControllerClass\EditChild?ParentTableID=3
```

Comment: If it only accepts one parameter, is it necessary to specify the parameter name when calling the action? (Not a criticism, legitimate query)

Comment: @jaredlee.exe - it depends on how your routes are setup. by default, `id` does not need to be specified, but if your param name is `ParentTableID` then you need to specify it.

Comment: Yes - that is how the model binder works.  Your parameter names must match with what the action method is expecting.  The same holds true if you pass an entire view model back in a post method, each property must match a name or the value will not be bound for that parameter / property.